# append the element before and after on drop it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website that use drag and drop functionality to build a website. But I'm facing the problem that the element is not being append before another element like the code I have shown. please help me so it can drop the elements before and after a specific element not just at the end of all the elements.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">button1</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">button2</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">button3</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4">button4</button>


</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

</div>
```

I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually quite tricky to achieve, you need to implement your own logic for inserting the element to the correct position in the list.

Here is an example where you can move items between `divs` and reorder items in the same `div`

(Note that I only implemented the logic for drag/drop items horizontally in a single line by using left offset, if you have multiple lines items list, you need to implement your own)

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id)
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text')
  // ev.currentTarget is the div that the elements are dropped
  const currentDragElementOffset = ev.clientX
  const items = ev.currentTarget.children
  //empty list, just append and return
  if (items.length === 0) {
    ev.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
    return
  }
  // non-empty list
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i]
    const {
      left,
      width
    } = item.getBoundingClientRect()
    // find the offset left from the center of the item
    const currentElementLeftOffset = left + width / 2;


    if (currentDragElementOffset < currentElementLeftOffset) {
      ev.currentTarget.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), item)
      return
    }

    // found no insertion point, that means item was dragged to the end of the list
    if (i === items.length - 1 && currentDragElementOffset > currentElementLeftOffset) {
      ev.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
  <p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
        button1
      </button>
    <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
        button2
      </button>
    <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">
        button3
      </button>
    <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4">
        button4
      </button>
  </div>

  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the CSS property [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

1. The drop zones must have `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` (see `.zone` in **Example - CSS**)
2. Each item that is `draggable` should have `style="order:` **number** `"` (see **Example - JS**)

Also, to avoid an item appending to another item, use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) in the `drop()` function (see `drop()` in **Example - JS**). In the example, the repetitive parts in HTML have been streamlined (see **Figure I**):

**Figure I**

| Original Post | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Attributes on each element in HTML | Attributes assigned to each element by `.forEach()` |
| [Inline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) on each element in HTML | [Onevent properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#using_onevent_properties) bound to each element by `.forEach()` |

### Example

**Details are commented**

```js
/*
Collect all .btn into a NodeList
Iterate through NodeList with .forEach()
Bind dragstart event to current <button>
Add inline style "order" with the value of current index
Add "draggable" attribute with the value of true
*/
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach((b, i) => {
  b.ondragstart = drag;
  b.style.order = i;
  b.setAttribute('draggable', true);
});

/*
Collect all .zone into a NodeList
Iterate through NodeList with .forEach()
Bind drop event to current <div>
Bind dragover event to current <div>
*/
document.querySelectorAll('.zone').forEach(z => {
  z.ondrop = drop;
  z.ondragover = allowDrop;
});

function allowDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drag(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  /*
  Change e.target to e.currentTarget to prevent any <button> 
  appending onto another <button>. e.currentTarget will always 
  point to .zone
  */
  e.currentTarget.append(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.zone {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the buttons back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div class="zone">
  <button id='b1' class='btn'>button1</button>
  <button id='b2' class='btn'>button2</button>
  <button id='b3' class='btn'>button3</button>
  <button id='b4' class='btn'>button4</button>
</div>

<div class="zone"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.prepend()` method for inserting element before the other element.

`Element.prepend()` method inserts a set of Node objects or string objects before the first child of the Element. String objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

---

Here's a Working Code :

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.prepend(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">button1</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">button2</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">button3</button>
  <button draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4">button4</button>


</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

</div>
```

Comment: i want to make it like that i can insert button four between btn1 and btn2